# Java - Observe WeakReference for when the referent is garbage collected?

Tags: java

I am wondering if there is a way to "observe" or "listen" to a `WeakReference` for when the referent object is removed from the `WeakReference` due to being garbage collected.

I simply need an efficient way to remove an object (which contains a `WeakReference`) from a `List` when the object's WeakReference's referent is disposed of.

I currently have a task iterating over the `List` checking the status of the `WeakReference` of each object in the list, but I'd like to ditch that system if its possible.

Thanks!

Comment: hmm, is this a use-case for... _PhantomReference_?!

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue.html should be used to meet your requirement.

See http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/java/archives/0507/shields/index.html how to write cache using ReferenceQueue and SoftReference.

`com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder` from guava is able to crate cache that uses soft or weak references. With `CacheBuilder`  you will not need to handle implementation details on your own- you will just get cache that can be used.

Another option is to use `java.util.WeakHashMap`.

Comment: The list I was speaking of is not of WeakReferences, but of objects which contain a WeakReference. Therefore, I don't think a Queue would be suitable for this situtation, but thanks for your answer

Comment: 'list objects which contain a WeakReference'. That looks strange too me. Do you really need such data structure? What problem it solves? I think if you use it in more standard way (list of *References) then there are tools that will do the internal plumbing for you. It is quite hard to test code that uses those Weak/Soft references. If you do it wrong, it will *almost* work, but fail precisely when it is needed (when you are low on memory)...

Comment: Well, the project I'm working on is a "bukkit plugin" for a Minecraft server. Therefore, there are "Entities" throughout the game world which can be removed at any moment. There is no way for me to be notified of the entity's removal, so storing the entity object in a weak reference is my solution to the issue of not having any notification of the entity's removal. I am storing the weak reference of the entity in a object because I need to accompany said entity with some other data. But coming to think about it I could probably use a map with weakly referenced keys of the entity and store the-

Comment: -excess data as a value.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. In that usecase it seems that ReferenceQueue would do you no good, but java.util.WeakHashMap looks just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The runtime system (garbage collector) is allowed to "collect" garbage at any given point in time. And to my knowledge, there is no mechanism that you could rely on here.

In other words: your **polling** approach is the one and only option here.

You could try some more hackish (or lets call it *pragmatic*) thing like:

1. A distinct call to System.gc()
2. Maybe some short sleeping
3. Inspection of that list

to increase the chance of finding items that require to be removed from your list. But maybe the real point is: why do you care: are your lists so huge that you keep running into issues because of your current implementation?

Finally, one other thought: if you are worried about having some "external" piece of code that is required to poll your list all the time; you might as well create your own List implementation ... that does exactly that: it uses WeakReferences for the objects you give to it; and it does all that periodic scanning under the cover - so that your application logic does **not** need to explicitly do that itself.

Answer (score 0):

That's what [PhantomReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html) is for. It doesn't prevent the object from being reclaimed, but when it is, it's put to a `ReferenceQueue` where you can perform any necessary actions (or just ignore it).

Comment: I always get a little giddy when PhantomReference is relevant. Because it never is

Comment: @Rogue Can't say I've ever needed it, but if I do, I'll know exactly why.

Comment: It turns out that I'm not going to need this- as I've decided to redo the data structure so that my WeakReferences are no longer nested within an object which would be placed in a list. But thank you for your answer

Comment: And now we see why it's never relevant

Answer (score 0):

Just needed something very similar, and in fact I did that using `java.lang.ref.Cleaner`: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html.

Here's the logic:

```
class A {
  private static final Cleaner CLEANER = Cleaner.create();

  private final WeakReference<Object> x;
  private final B y;
}

class B {
  void clean();
}
```

And then

```
B b = new B();
A a = new A(new WeakReference<>(object), b);
A.CLEANER.register(a, b::clean);
```